# VueJS: Why counter does not increase on post increment but works on pre-increment

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7rmjee2/), why the counter does not increase on calling the `increment()` function. Have set the counter to increment post assignment to itself so after clicking on event button (more than once), the counter variable should increment.

- **Note**:
  If I do pre-increment instead of post-increment like this, `this.counter = ++this.counter;` that works.

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
   <h2>some text</h2>
   <p>{{ counter }}</p>
   <button @click="increment">Increment</button>      
</div>
```

**VueJS**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function(){
        this.counter = this.counter++;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

That has nothing to do with VueJS. That's a plain prefix / suffix problem. Look at this code:

```
var test = 0;
console.log(test++);
console.log(++test);
```

Also, you can shorten this line `this.counter = this.counter++;` to `this.counter++`, since `this.counter++;` is the shorthand for `this.counter = this.counter + 1;`